# gradle build file name with profile

Tags: java, jenkins, gradle

I'm working on jenkins, spring boot project.

1. How to package my jar file with specific name, ex) project-{$profile}-{$date}.jar
2. How to pass profile value when I run gradle build?
3. How to deploy my jar file on remote server, and run jar?

Please let me know any gradle script about this.

Thank you for your help in advance

Comment: You copy the jar to a remote server, which has JRE installed. Then just execute `java -jar <jar-filename>`

Comment: Hi. This looks like 3 questions in 1. Consider splitting them into three separate questions instead to get more focus on each. Regarding question number 3, it depends a bit on how your server is setup and how you want to run your application (Straight Java? In a container?). When posting the 3rd question, add some details about your server setup.